# I can't catch an exception

Tags: c#, .net

I have this piece of code:

```
try
{
    var files = from folder in paths
                from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, pattern, searchOption)
                select new Foo() { folder = folder, fileName = file };

    Parallel.ForEach(files, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = _maxDegreeOfParallelism }, currentFile =>
    {
        DoWork(currentFile);
    });
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

When I have an exception in `Directory.EnumerateFiles`, I can't catch this exception in this piece of code. The exception is caught by the method that calls this snippet.

From Visual Studio, in debug mode, the exception is caught by Visual Studio (for example a `DirectoryNotFoundException`).

Comment: You have to add the try/catch within the foreach.  See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You could also call `EnumerateFiles` before the LINQ expression and wrap that call in a try/catch.

Comment: Suppose in the parallel loop one file throws an exception and another one throws its own. How could you deal with two "parallel" exceptions in a single try-catch block?

Comment: you could call `files.ToList()` before the `Parallel` and then your catch would fire.

Comment: Just wondering if you should be passing `folder` to `Directory.EnumerateFiles` instead of `path`?

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that you are invoking the code asynchronously here:

```
Parallel.ForEach(files, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = _maxDegreeOfParallelism }, currentFile =>
{
    DoWork(currentFile);
});
```

This makes the calls on separate threads and not on your main thread.

Use a `try & catch` block like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(files, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = _maxDegreeOfParallelism }, currentFile =>
{
    try
    { 
         DoWork(currentFile);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { ... } 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to catch the Directory not found exception you may add the two lines

```
catch (DirectoryNotFoundException dnfe)
{
  throw dnfe;
}
```

Comment: Whilst it is definitely better to catch the specific exception you're interested in, in this instance the OP isn't able to catch any exceptions where they want to - adding this to the code will not help.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to catch any exceptions that may be thrown while in the loop is to use **System.AggregateException**. This is because any exception thrown in any one thread in the loop might cause other threads to throw exceptions too.